# SWTException in SWTBot-Test: Why is it thrown in Tycho+Surefire?

Tags: java, maven, tycho, surefire, swtbot

I get an `SWTException:Invalid thread access` from all of my SWTBot-Test. They all turn green when they where started from eclipse, so the problem must be inside the pom.xml I guess. How to solve this?

I use the following arguments and dependencies in the pom.xml of the test-fragment:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
<artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${tycho.version}</version>
<configuration>
    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
    <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>300</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
    <useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>
    <useUIThread>false</useUIThread>
    <showEclipseLog>true</showEclipseLog>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
            <artifactId>my.host.ui.bundle</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
            <artifactId>org.hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <type>installable-unit</type>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.ui</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <type>installable-unit</type>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.ui.workbench</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.finder</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swtbot.junit4_x</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.finder</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <type>p2-nstallable-unit</type>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.ui.navigator</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.ui.views</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're on osx, cf. [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg00467.html)

otherwise, pls. provide more detail about the failing test

Comment: What details are useful, other than a StackTrace?

Comment: I meant the actual code in the test. First few lines of the stack trace might also help.

Answer (score 0):

How do you tell surefire which tests to run for you ?
Did you configure following?

```
<configuration>
                ...
                <testSuite>bundle.symbolic.name.of.test.plugin</testSuite>
                <testClass>package.of.test.suite.YourTestSuiteOrClass</testClass>
                ...
</configuration>
```